# Page break in incorrect position in resume

Tags: page-breaking, resume

The pagebreak in this resume is in the wrong spot.  I would like latex to automatically put a page break in the right spot.

EDIT
I would like items to be cut off by a page break and continued on the next page.  My problem is that what happens right now is that if a page break is in the middle of a section, the items that fit on the page are shown, and the items that do not are not displayed at all.  The next page starts with the next section.  That is my problem.

I don't want to manually tell latex where to put a page break because my resume with change with time, I have many different versions, and I don't want to specify it every time.  The document is attached.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{python}


\ifx\UseOption\undefined
\def\UseOption{optb}
\fi


\textheight=10in
\pagestyle{empty}
%\raggedbottom
\raggedright


%  \renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{cg}
  %\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lgrcmr}


\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }
% DEFINITIONS FOR RESUME


\newcommand{\area}[2]{\vspace*{-9pt} \begin{verse}\textbf{#1}   #2 \end{verse}  }


\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\}


\newcommand{\header}[1]{{\hspace*{-15pt}\vspace*{6pt} \textsc{#1}} \vspace*{-6pt} \lineunder}


\newcommand{\employer}[3]{{ \textbf{#1} (#2)\\ \underline{\textbf{\emph{#3}}}\\  }}


\newcommand{\contact}[3]{
\vspace*{-8pt}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \scshape {#1}}
\lineunder
#2 \\
#3
\end{center}
\vspace*{-8pt}
}
\newenvironment{achievements}{\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\topsep 0pt \itemsep -2pt}}{\vspace*{4pt}\end{list}}
\newcommand{\schoolwithcourses}[4]{
 \textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3\\
 %#4 $\bullet$  Selected Coursework:\\
\vspace*{5pt}
}
\newcommand{\school}[4]{
 \textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3\\
#4 \\
}
% END RESUME DEFINITIONS


\begin{document}
\small
\smallskip
\vspace*{-44pt}


\contact{Awesome person}
{Awesome home}
 {Awesome phone number $\bullet$ Awesome email}  
 % $\bullet$ Awesome website}


\header{Education}


 \textbf{Masters of Awesome}  \hfill 2011\\
Awesome University \\
\hspace*{-5pt}
\\
 \textbf{Honours Awsomeness} \hfill 2006\\
Awesome University
\hspace*{-5pt}
\\




\header{Honors and Awards}
\begin{achievements}

\item  Major Awesomeness, 2007-2009
\item  Total Awesomenewss, 2002
\item  The Awesome Award

\end{achievements}

\header{Skills}


\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\begin{verse}
 \textbf{Awesome Skills}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
   \item Awesome
  \end{itemize}   
 \end{multicols}
 \end{verse}
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{$\bullet$}}$}


\header{Job Experience}

\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}  
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to put the elements you do not want cut over two pages in a `minipage` environment. For instance:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\employer{Awesome Centre}{2008-2011}{Awesome analyst}
Dr. Awesome, Awesome Centre
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  \item Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Indeed, and they could be wrapped into a (say) 'employment' environment, which would help maintaining cleaner code.

Comment: This is useful information and I may use it in the future.  However for this question I DO want some items to show on one page and continued on the next.  What I don't want is some items to show on the first page and the remaining items skipped entirely with the next page starting at the next section.  That is my problem.

Comment: @denilw -- Then it looks like your problem is the `\textheight=10in`.  Unless you know what you are doing, setting page dimensions properly is an involved task.  You should use the `geometry` package instead.  Your use of `\hspace` and `\vspace` everywhere is also problematic: it will not be an easy document to maintain.  You need better separation of form(at) and content, which you could achieve, e.g., by creating appropriate `\newenvironment`s.  It is probably also wiser to use dimensions relative to your fonts (e.g., not `pt` and `cm`, but `ex`, `em`, and `\*skip`).

Comment: Removing '\textheight=10in' solves the problem.  I will look into making the formatting easier to maintain as you suggested.  I was using a template.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question but how can I google "\*skip"?  Is there a good page on it?